# Integral of a positive function over a smaller interval is lesser than that over a larger interval?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am wondering whether the following is a true statement:

For $f(x): [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$, where $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$, if $a \leq c \leq d \leq b$, then

$$\int_{c}^{d} f(x) dx \leq \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$$.

This seems true intuitively, but I can't seem to verify it with my current textbook (Rudin's "Principals of mathematical analysis"). Could someone possibly verify this and provide a proof or some direction toward a proof?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^c f(x)dx+\int_c^d f(x)dx+\int_d^b f(x)dx$$

Comment: So, because each of the terms on the right-hand side are at least zero, then they are each lesser than the term on the left-hand side?

Comment: It seems like you have the idea! Since $\int_a^c f(x)dx\ge 0$ and $\int_d^b f(x)dx\ge 0,$ then we can conclude the desired result.

Comment: The only adjustment I'd make is that instead of saying "lesser," I'd say "no greater."

Comment: This might not be the right place to ask, but I just wanted to confirm that the inequality in my question would definitely not be true if $f(x)$ could take on negative values. Is that correct?

Comment: You're correct. If $f$ can take on negative values, the result need not hold. For example, consider $$\int_{-2}^21-x^2dx$$ and $$\int_{-1}^11-x^2dx.$$